# How does one stay informed about what is the latest Firebase beta?

Tags: firebase

My problem is that when a new beta version is released, I don't know about it, nor do I know what fixes/improvements the new version addresses. Does anyone know where this information can be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Firebase - Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases).

Release Notes include Latest SDK Versions and release notes for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), [JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js), [C++](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/cpp-relnotes), [Unity](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity), [Admin Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node), [Admin Java](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java), [Admin Python](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/python), [Admin Go](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/go), [Admin .Net](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/dotnet).

And also Firebase Weekly Roundup.

Also you will find beta version for JavaScript SDK [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase?activeTab=versions).

Comment: Thank you, but that page does not cover the beta versions; I'm interested in the betas, for example, the latest currently being `9.0.0-beta.5`.

Comment: @RaphaelMartinSchindler Unfortunately, There is no page for betas. but you can find betas version in [Firebase - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase?activeTab=versions). Firebase add release notes for the released version only.

Comment: Kevin, the link to npm is precisely what I was looking for. Edit your answer to reflect that, and I'll accept it.